# Slow transition when pushViewController is called Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pushviewcontroller, background-thread

I have the following code in `ViewControllerA`

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let controller = ViewControllerB (collectionViewLayout: layout)

controller.contentData = self.users_cities[indexPath.row].content
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Now when `let controller = ViewControllerB (collectionViewLayout: layout)`
 is called, the `viewDidLoad` method of `ViewControllerB` is executed and the UI is setup for `ViewControllerB`. The problem is that this makes the UI of `ViewControllerA` freeze for a few seconds before `ViewControllerB` is pushed. Is there a different way of doing this in order to avoid this problem? The natural solution would be to run that on the background thread, but as far as I know, you shouldn't setup views on the background thread.

Comment: Maybe you have some heavy lifting happening on the main thread in ViewControllerB's ViewDidLoad and ViewWillLoad functions.

Comment: Maybe have those run asynchronously in another thread?

Comment: @SahandTheGreat I do, I do a lot of view creation and assigning constraints, but I thought that you cannot run anything related to `UIViews` on background threads?